# Reputation earned from answering a particular tag questions

Tags: support, reputation

How do I find the reputation score earned from answering questions on a particular tag? Is that possible? It need not be a perfect, but a general idea regarding the rep earned is sufficient.

Comment: Your rep or someone else?

Answer (score 2):

If you've been very active in a tag, the "All time" values on the [stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=c%23&sort=stats&pagesize=50) may help (although this counts votes, not rep, which isn't quite the same). Otherwise... data dump?

Comment: Didn't that page used to have the current user's stats at the bottom, or have I imagined it?

Comment: Yes it did. I belive that was removed because it was the only non-cacheable piece of data and was probably expensive to calculate.  You can get your numbers from the data-dump (or a stackql query) though.